# Is $f\colon Y'\to Y$ continuous?

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

Consider $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $T\colon X\to X$ continuous, describing the following dynamics: For $\eta\in X$ let $\eta(y)$ describe the y-th position in the bi-infite sequence $\eta$. Then in the next time step, a 1 becomes 1 2, a 2 becomes a 0 and a 0 becomes a 1 iff at least one of its two neighbour positions is a 1.

Furthermore, define
$$
Y:=\left\{(x,Tx,T^2x,\ldots): x\in X\right\},~~~Y':=\left\{(\ldots,T^{-2}x,T^{-1}x,x,Tx,T^2x,\ldots): x\in X\right\}
$$
and
$$
f\colon Y'\to Y,~~(\ldots,T^{-2}x,T^{-1}x,x,Tx,T^2x,\ldots)\longmapsto(x,Tx,T^2x,\ldots).
$$
Is the function $f$ continuous?

---

I think we give both $Y$ and $Y'$ their product topology.

So I think it suffices to show that for each $i\geq 0$ the conjugacy
$$
\pi_i\circ f
$$
with $\pi_i\colon Y\to Y, (x,Tx,T^2x,\ldots)\longmapsto T^ix$ is continuous.

But that's the case, because the product topology on $Y$ is the topology for which all projections $\pi$ are continuous and
$$
\pi_i\circ f=\pi_i.
$$

Ok?

Comment: Is $T$ assumed bijective or are the $T^{-n}x$ assumed to be sets? Or is in fact $T$ the translation map?

Comment: Oh sorry, forget to mention. T describes the following dynamics: If $\eta\in X$ and $\eta(x)$ is the position x, then a 1 becomes a 2, a 2 becomes a 0 and a 0 becomes a 1 if at least of it two neigbor positions is a 1.

Comment: And no... $T^{-n}x$ for a fixed $x\in X$ is a bi-infite series, no set.